# PocketSphinx ps_process_raw sample buffer size effect

Tags: c++, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

In pocketsphinx [tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/), the ps_process_raw function was called with a buffer of 512 int16s:

```
int16 buf[512];
while (!feof(fh)) {
    size_t nsamp;
    nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
    ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
}
```

However in their [own source code](https://cmusphinx.github.io/doc/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx_8c_source.html) called by the command line interface, they used 256:

```
total = 0;
while (!feof(rawfh)) {
    int16 data[256];
    size_t nread;
    nread = fread(data, sizeof(*data), sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data), rawfh); 
    ps_process_raw(ps, data, nread, FALSE, FALSE);
    total += nread;
}
```

Elsewhere I've seen 2048 as well. If I understand correctly, given input audio is preferred in 16khz, 512 samples corresponds to around 30 ms of sound, which lines up with what most speech recognition guides seem to suggest.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how sample buffer size affects performance (accuracy and speed), and why it isn't consistent across different 'official' sources.

I'm on the latest sphinx version using the C++ API.

Comment: If I understand this correctly the size of your buffer doesn't really impact accuracy. It could inpact speed though. Larger buffers read more of a file at a time and in my perfessional experience it's faster to load files directly into memory then process them rather than processing them as you read them from disk to memory. What does affect accuracy is your file format and the tutorial is extremely specific about what format the file needs to be in if you was to create your own.

Comment: @johnathon I see, thanks. I'll play around and see how results differ.